# Linking to a specific position on one page from a different page based on a json array variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am re-developing a clients site using AngularJs and since they list businesses for sale, I've placed all their data in a json file, then populated a page with ng-repeat.  Everything works great, but on their home page I used ng-repeat | limitTo:3 to show just a couple of the listings.  Is there a way of hyper-linking the listings on the home page to the position they reside at on the listings page?  I know html you can use the #id method to move to a section, but I've never done it when link from another page.

Thank you.

Comment: You can tack a query string to the URL - use `$location` to parse the URL on the list page and then goto the ID you passed over.

Comment: thank you.  I've searched and found everything from $location to autoscroll and with varying examples.  Since I am using ng-repeat, I need it to be dynamic.  Would it be too much to ask for an example? Thank you.